# cPickle - Ignore stuff it can't serialize instead of raising an exception

Tags: python, pickle

I'm using `cPickle` to serialize data that's used for logging.

I'd like to be able to throw whatever I want into an object, then serialize it. Usually this is fine with `cPickle`, but just ran into a problem where one of the objects I wanted to serialize contained a function. This caused `cPickle` to raise an exception.

I would rather `cPickle` just skipped over stuff it can't deal with instead of causing the whole process to implode.

What is a good way to make this happen?

Comment: Uh, catch the raised exception?

Comment: Catching the exception wouldn't help because pickling would still fail instead of "skip stuff it can't deal with".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming that you're looking for a best-effort solution and you're okay if the unpickled results don't function properly.

For your particular use case, you may want to [register a pickle handler](http://docs.python.org/2.6/library/copy_reg.html) for function objects.  Just make it a dummy handler that's good enough for your best-effort purposes.  Making a handler for functions is possible, it's rather tricky.  To avoid affecting other code that pickles, you'll probably want to deregister the handler when exiting your logging code.

Here's an example (without any deregistration):

```
import cPickle
import copy_reg
from types import FunctionType

# data to pickle: note that o['x'] is a lambda and they
# aren't natively picklable (at this time)
o = {'x': lambda x: x, 'y': 1}

# shows that o is not natively picklable (because of
# o['x'])
try:
    cPickle.dumps(o)
except TypeError:
    print "not natively picklable"
else:
    print "was pickled natively"

# create a mechanisms to turn unpickable functions int
# stub objects (the string "STUB" in this case)
def stub_pickler(obj):
    return stub_unpickler, ()
def stub_unpickler():
    return "STUB"
copy_reg.pickle(
    FunctionType,
    stub_pickler, stub_unpickler)

# shows that o is now picklable but o['x'] is restored
# to the stub object instead of its original lambda
print cPickle.loads(cPickle.dumps(o))
```

It prints:

```
not natively picklable
{'y': 1, 'x': 'STUB'}
```

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, try [`cloudpickle`](https://github.com/cloudpipe/cloudpickle):

```
>>> import cloudpickle
>>> squared = lambda x: x ** 2
>>> pickled_lambda = cloudpickle.dumps(squared)

>>> import pickle
>>> new_squared = pickle.loads(pickled_lambda)
>>> new_squared(2)
4
```

[image: we can pickle that]

`pip install cloudpickle` and live your dreams. The same dreams lived by dask, IPython parallel, and PySpark.